# Gedit roscpp debugger?

Tags: ros-hydro, roscpp, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm writing some nodes in roscpp using gedit.  I'm encountering some errors, and am getting tired of tracing them using print statements.  I would like to use a debugger to fix my code, but am not sure exactly how to go about this in gedit (and also in ROS, if that makes a difference).  I've read a little about GDB, but am not sure how to integrate it into gedit, and again, I'm not sure if the fact that I'm writing ROS nodes rather than regular C++ stuff makes things more complicated.

Anyone have any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189535/gedit-roscpp-debugger?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gedit is just a text editor and I doubt that there is a debugger plugin for that. Try using a propper IDE like qtcreator (`sudo apt-get install qtcreator`) which naturally understand CMakeLists.txt files so there is no set-up needed. Just run it from the terminal with `qtcreator my_catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt`.

See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/34966/debugging-ros-package-with-qtcreator/) on how to use the debugger.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2